# DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: ratio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the cells are filled with floats, and the column names are in datetime format, in the form year+quarter - for example '1995Q2'. I want to divide the values of two of these columns and store the result in a new column. I have done this:

```
df['ratio'] = df['2008Q3'].div(df['2009Q2'])
```

but I get the errors:

```
ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: ratio
```

and

```
DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: ratio
```

When I try this:

```
ratio_column = df['2008Q3'].div(df['2009Q2'])
df['ratio'] = df.add(ratio_column)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: can only call with other PeriodIndex-ed objects
```

Any help? Thank you!

---

The errors can be reproduced with the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.period_range('1999-1-1', '2000-1-1', freq='Q')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, len(columns))), columns=columns)
df['ratio'] = df['1999Q1'].div(df['1999Q2'])

ratio_column = df['1999Q1'].div(df['1999Q2'])
df['ratio'] = df.add(ratio_column)
```

Comment: Please post `df.info()`.

Comment: @unutbu :

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 10730 entries, (New York, New York) to (Wisconsin, Holland)
Data columns (total 4 columns):
2008Q3    9884 non-null float64
2008Q4    9885 non-null float64
2009Q1    9912 non-null float64
2009Q2    9930 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 419.1+ KB
None

Comment: I've added an example which reproduces the error messages. Please check that the example is sufficiently similar to your situation. In particular, is `df.columns` a PeriodIndex?

Comment: @unutbu
The answer to both questions is yes. I get the same error when I run the code you posted, and df.columns is a PeriodIndex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises when one attempts to add a string column name such as `'ratio'` to a PeriodIndex (for the columns). The PeriodIndex can only contain `Periods`, not strings.

The usual way to add a new column,

```
df['ratio'] = ...
```

does not work because it assumes `'ratio'` can be added to the current column index.

To avoid this problem, we'll need to change the PeriodIndex to a generic Index which can accomodate both Periods and strings. One way to do this is to use `pd.concat`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.period_range('1999-1-1','2000-1-1', freq='Q')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, len(columns))), columns=columns)
ratio = pd.DataFrame({'ratio': df['1999Q1'].div(df['1999Q2'])})
df = pd.concat([df, ratio], axis=1)

print(df)
```

yields

```
   1999Q1  1999Q2  1999Q3  1999Q4  2000Q1     ratio
0       9       0       3       4       6       inf
1       3       9       5       5       3  0.333333
2       2       6       8       7       0  0.333333
3       0       8       7       7       3  0.000000
```

Alternatively, if you don't really need the column labels to be Periods, then you could convert them to strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, len(columns))), columns=columns)
df.columns = map(str, df.columns)
df['ratio'] = df['1999Q1'].div(df['1999Q2'])
```